# Failed to invoke one service from another service using DNS for services in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service

I have set up a AWS kops cluster for Kubernetes, i have multiple microservices where in each application need to interact with one another.

**Scenario: My ta2carbon app tries to invoke a function in ta1carbon app through service(dns) name.**

**Result: It is failing with timeout error by trying to hit to port 80 (but configured port -3000)**

my nodejs app console log,
    apiUrl: http://ta1carbon/api/app1/app1Func2

```
{ Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 100.66.7.165:80
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:992:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1014:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1186:14)
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '100.66.7.165',
  port: 80 }
```

same error logs for curl, when i tried to curl my ta1carbon app inside ta2carbon pod.

```
root@ta2carbon-5fdcfb97cc-8j4nl:/home/appHome# curl -i http://ta1carbon/api/app1/app1Func2
curl: (7) Failed to connect to ta1carbon port 80: Connection timed out
```

but my defined port in service.yaml is 3000 not 80!
below are the yml configurations for service for both microservices.

ta1carbon service yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ta1carbon
  labels:
    app: ta1carbon
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 3000
    targetPort: 3000
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: ta1carbon
```

ta2carbon service yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ta2carbon
  labels:
    app: ta2carbon
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 3001
    targetPort: 3001
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: ta2carbon
```

And below is the describe service details for both ta1carbon and ta2 carbon.

```
kubectl describe service ta1carbon
Name:              ta1carbon
Namespace:         default
Labels:            app=ta1carbon
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app=ta1carbon
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                100.66.7.165
Port:              <unset>  3000/TCP
TargetPort:        3000/TCP
Endpoints:         100.96.1.13:3000
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>

kubectl describe service ta2carbon
Name:              ta2carbon
Namespace:         default
Labels:            app=ta2carbon
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app=ta2carbon
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                100.67.129.126
Port:              <unset>  3001/TCP
TargetPort:        3001/TCP
Endpoints:         100.96.1.12:3001
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

So based on what i observe, for the url http://ta1carbon/api/app1/app1Func2 
service dns **ta1carbon** is being resolved in to **100.67.24.69:80** resulting in timeout.

but however if i curl in to **100.67.24.69:3000** from inside ta2carbon pod i get a **success response**

Also if i change my service yaml **- port: 80** and deploy and test again i get **success response**

i am finding this behaviour in kubernetes quite weird, not sure weather i am making mistake or with environment.

My query is -

**why is it resolving service ta1carbon in to 100.67.24.69:80 and timing out, when the port should have been 3000!**

Any input on this will be much appreciated. please let me know what is missing in this.

Comment: Is it possible to raise an issue with AWS team (Kubernetes experts in AWS) parallely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DNS resolves a doman name to an IP address, not an IP address + port.

There are two potential solutions:

1. Modify your application source to issue API requests to `http://ta1carbon:3000`
2. Set the `port` on your `ta1carbon` service to `80`.

I recommend going with option 2. In this scenario, you are taking advantage of the power of Kubernetes services. Kubernetes will expose the service on port 80, but send requests to the pods backing the service on port 3000 (because of the `targetPort: 3000`).

Comment: Thank you, i had already tried the 2nd option it worked. Now tried the first option too, both works. But however i wanted to understand, as default if i define port and target port to 3000 for a service shouldn't my service name ta1carbon properly resolve? why is it resulting in timeout?

Comment: @ShruthiBhaskar It is because Kubernetes service discovery is backed by DNS, and DNS does not tell your application which port number it should use. 

In other words, when your application asks DNS to resolve "ta1carbon", DNS responds with an IP address that the application can use to talk to the service. DNS will not tell the application what port to use. It is the responsibility of the application to know which port to use. 

Kubernetes exposes environment variables with the port numbers that you can use in your application. In your case: `TA1CARBON_SERVICE_PORT`